# Enviar datos desde un Javascript a PHP para luego usar Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmyadmin

estoy en un proyecto en el que uso javascript para tomar información de algunos formularios y me gustaría poder trabajar con una base de datos a través de phpmyadmin pero según tengo entendido debo pasar antes todos los datos que he tomado a través de javascript a php. Ahí mi duda.

¿Cuál sería la forma más sencilla de pasar un dato obtenido de un formulario HTML por javascript a PHP para ya ahí comunicarme con phpmyadmin?

Por ejemplo, un usuario se intenta logear a través de un formulario login, esos datos los recibe javascript, javascript se los pasa a Php y este comunica con la base de datos que nos da un OK o un KO según el resultado de la consulta.

Siento si me he explicado mal. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Javier, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Aqui las preguntas de orientacion son demasiado amplias. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Imagino que quieres comunicarte con el servidor MySQL, y que usas phpMyAdmin para gestionar el contenido de éste de manera gráfica. Si es así echa un vistazo a [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) y [PDO/mysql](http://php.net/pdo-mysql).

Comment: Utiliza AJAX, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy abierta y además de no tener código hecho por parte de quien pregunta... esta pregunta ya se ha hecho. No entiendo por qué hay usuarios que  insisten en dar respuesta a preguntas con estos problemas, haciendo menos eficiente este sitio web a la hora de buscar soluciones a problemas comunes...  Haz el recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tal como dicen arriba, debes usar ajax.

Acá te dejo un enlace donde expliqué en su momento como funciona.

http://codigodeleonardo.blogspot.mx/2015/10/ajax-hacer-una-llamada-al-servidor.html

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de la función ajax, adaptado a tu duda. La parte PHP simplemente es manejar ya que recibes esos datos, realizar la conexión con la base de datos y según los datos devueltos, finaliza el php siempre con un `echo`
del resultado en formato json (para que sea más fácil de manejar, aunque puedes devolver simplemente "OK" o "KO") con `json_encode(respuesta,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

```js
$("form").submit(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  //la url en la que esté tu php
  url  :"url/compurebaLogin.php",
  //(aquí GET o POST)
  method :  "POST",
  data : {
    "nombreUsuario": $("#usr").val(),
    "pass" : $("#pass").val()
    }
  }).done(function(response){
    //Aquí te devuelve el OK o KO dependiendo de lo que hagas en PHP
    //En php recibes en este caso concreto $_POST['nombreUsuario'] y $_POST['pass']
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="usr"/>
<input tpe="password" id="pass"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: He visto tus respuestas recientes. tienen buena calidad y explicacion :D  tan solo recordarte que no todas las preguntas han de responderse. Fijate que tengan una buena calidad o informacion suficiente. Un saludo y gracias por aportar

Comment: @lois6b Ok, tomo nota del consejo, gracias por él. Comencé hace nada a utilizar la página para algo más que simplemente buscar información, y quiero empezar con buen pie ;)